# Apply.weekly for non unique date column?

Tags: r, data.table, subset, zoo

I currently have the below `data.table` with `Name` and `Id` recycling per day.

```
Date            Name                Id           Widgets
2016-12-31      Bob Jones           0052A00001   5
2016-12-31      James Smith         0052A00002   25
2016-12-31      Tom Wilson          0052A00003   29
...
2016-01-31      Bob Jones           0052A00001   8
2016-01-31      James Smith         0052A00002   18
2016-01-31      Tom Wilson          0052A00003   20
```

Is it possible to apply the `zoo` function `apply.weekly` to this since there are not unique values per date? If not, what is the easiest way to aggregate this by a weekly value (or period of another length- say 4 days) and create groupings according to that?

Comment: I'm not sure if `apply.weekly` works on `data.frame` or `data.table`. You could convert `Date` to weekly values and then use the `aggregate` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a grouping first before you match in the week. You can play around with `cut` to get your desired grouping.

```
grpWeek <- data.table(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by="1 day"))[,
    list(Date, 
        DT_Week=week(Date),
        Week_Num=format(Date, "%W"),
        User_Week=cut(Date, breaks=52, labels=paste0("Week",1:52)))]

dt <- fread("Date,Name,Id,Widgets
2016-12-31,Bob Jones,0052A00001,5
2016-12-31,James Smith,0052A00002,25
2016-12-31,Tom Wilson,0052A00003,29
2016-01-31,Bob Jones,0052A00001,8
2016-01-31,James Smith,0052A00002,18
2016-01-31,Tom Wilson,0052A00003,20")
dt[,Date:=as.Date(Date)]

grpWeek[dt, on="Date"]
```